# How to disable ruby bundler text output?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Whenever I run a ruby script through bundler it always gives me output similar to:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://foo.bar.com/........
...
Using ...
Fetching ...
Installing ...
....
Bundle complete! 19 Gemfile dependencies, 145 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

How can I disable this in bundler so that it just shows the output of the actual script being run?

Comment: Is this from `bundle exec`?

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is to tell it to keep quiet about what it's doing:

```sh
bundle install --quiet
```

You may want to redirect it to a file in case something happens and it couldn't install gems:

```sh
bundle install > /tmp/bundle-install.out
```

Where you can inspect that if things go awry.